# Android Retrofit pass parameter

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to fetch a single post by post-id,
I am getting error while passing the post id.
I've tried several methods but non of them has returned the right respond.

I tried already:

```
@GET("?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/")
    Call<SinglePost> getSinglePost(@FieldMap Map<String, String> map); 

@GET("?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/")
    Call<SinglePost> getSinglePost(@QueryMap Map<String, String> map);

@GET("?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/")
    Call<SinglePost> getSinglePost(@QueryMap<String, String> map);

@GET("?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/{postid}")
    Call<SinglePost> getSinglePost(@Path("postid")int postid);

@GET("?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/{postid}")
    Call<SinglePost> getSinglePost(@Path("postid")int postid);

@GET("?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/{postid}")
    Call<SinglePost> getSinglePost(@Field("postid") int postid);
```

this is the original link
https://www.mywordpress.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/3561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your API call like this

```
@GET("/")
Call<SinglePost> getSinglePost(@QueryMap Map<String, String> map);
```

Make a map of parameter and pass it when initializing your API call

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("rest_route", "/wp/v2/posts/3561");
Call<SinglePost> call = apiService.getSinglePost(map);
```

Comment: Wow, this is working perfect, thanks you very much for your help. Little bit confusing but it worked perfect.  Can you please tell me in what cases i can use this format?  @GET("?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/{postid}")
    Call<SinglePost> getSinglePost(@Path("postid")int postid);

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I am not sure about it. Generally we declare fixed path paramters in @GET and variable paths as well as query params are passed at runtime. The problem with your code was you were declaring query params with @ GET